# Alternate way to say "random ass ..."

Tags: questions

I'm writing something for school and I'm assuming I can't cuss in it. For a sentence I'm writing about how a random ass person approached me. Now I was wondering an alternate cleaner way to say something like "Then this random ass dude approached me from the side of the street."

Comment: Hate to state the obvious but: "Then this *random dude* approached me."

Comment: Good comment by @Silenus (I'll up vote it momentarily), but I like *random ass dude*. It's real, authentic. It doesn't pull any punches. It doesn't compromise.

Comment: Just for interest, do you mean "random" in the sense of the actual meaning of the word or as slang for "bad"?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>random ass dude</strike>

> **stranger**: A person whom one does not know; a person who is neither a friend nor an acquaintance.

[*from Wikitionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stranger)

Comment: If that's supposed to be a dictionary citation you are missing your source. If not, you are missing a reference for your answer ;)